# Access handle value using element API

Tags: plugin-elementapi

I'm using the [Element API](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api) and would like to return content based on it's handle. The two handles I am trying to return are called appLogo and appVideo:

```
'api/featured-apps.json' => [
  'elementType' => 'Entry',
  'criteria' => [
    'section' => 'apps',
    'appFeatured' => '1',
  ],
  'transformer' => function (EntryModel $entry) {
    return [
      'title' => $entry->title,
      'logo' => $entry->appLogo,
      'video' => $entry->appVideo,
    ];
  }
],
```

This does not work, do I need to access images/videos in a different way? Ideally, I'd like the relative path returned for both logo and video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing it like this:

```
'api/featured-apps.json' => [
  'elementType' => 'Entry',
  'criteria' => [
    'section' => 'apps',
    'appFeatured' => '1',
  ],
  'transformer' => function (EntryModel $entry) { 
    $logos = [];
    foreach ($entry->appLogo as $image) {
      $logos[] = $image->url;
    }

    $videos = [];
    foreach ($entry->appVideo as $video) {
      $videos[] = $video->url;
    }

    return [
      'title' => $entry->title,
      'logo' => $logos,
      'video' => $videos,
    ];
  }
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both `appLogo` and `appVideo` are Asset fields, they will always return an array, even if there is only one asset selected.

```
'logo' => $entry->appLogo->first(),
'video' => $entry->appVideo->first(),
```

Should do what you're looking for.

Comment: That didn't work